# Autoscroll graph using MpAndroidChart library

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I am using MpAndroidChart library and DynamicalAdding activity to get realtime graph.my realtime data is coming from handler.I am passing this data to  addEntry() function.Now this function is called properly and some values are plotted but when graph takes all available space on scrren it does not autoscroll.Please give me modified solution code.Below is my code:

```
public class DynamicalAddingActivity extends Activity implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

BluetoothSerialService mSerialService = null;
private LineChart mChart;

Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case BluetoothSerialService.SUCCESS_CONNECT:
            /*BluetoothSerialService.connectedThread = new BluetoothSerialService.ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected!", 0).show();
            String s = "successfully connected";*/
            BluetoothSerialService.connectedThread.start();
            break;
        case BluetoothSerialService.MESSAGE_READ:

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String strIncom;
            try {
                String mystr = new String(readBuf,"UTF-8");
                Log.d("strIncom", mystr);
                String[] params = mystr.split(" ");

                   for(int i=0;i<params.length;i++){

                   String temp = params[i];
                   temp=temp.trim();
                   String [] parts=temp.split(",");
                   int len=parts.length;
                   if(len==3){

                       //Accel-X
                       String x=parts[0];
                       x=x.replace("0","");
                       x=x.trim();
                       double value1;
                       int c1=x.indexOf("-,1");
                       int count1=StringUtils.countMatches(x, "-");


                       if( x.length()==1&& x.indexOf("-")==0){
                           value1=1.0;
                       }
                       else if(x==" "&&x.isEmpty()==true){
                           value1=1.0;
                       }
                       else if(x.length()==0){
                           value1=1.0;
                   }
                       else if(count1>1 &&c1!=-1){
                           value1=1.0;
                       }
                       else if(x.indexOf("-",1)!=-1){
                           value1=1.0;
                       }
                       else{
                           value1 = Double.parseDouble(x);
                       }
                       Log.d("Accel-X",String.valueOf(value1));
                       addEntry(value1);

            }}} 

            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 



            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_linechart_noseekbar);
    BluetoothSerialService.gethandler(mHandler);
    mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
    mChart.setDrawYValues(false);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.scrollBy(100, 0);
    addEmptyData();

    mChart.invalidate();
}

int[] mColors = ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS;

private void addEntry(double value1) {
    float v=(float) value1;
    LineData data = mChart.getData();

    if(data != null) {

        LineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
        // set.addEntry(...);

        if (set == null) {
            set = createSet();
            data.addDataSet(set);
        }

        data.addEntry(new Entry( v, set.getEntryCount()), 0);

        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // redraw the chart
        mChart.invalidate();   
    }
}




private void removeDataSet() {

    LineData data = mChart.getData();

    if(data != null) {

        data.removeDataSet(data.getDataSetByIndex(data.getDataSetCount() - 1));

        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();   
    }
}

private void addEmptyData() {

    // create 30 x-vals
    String[] xVals = new String[30];

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        xVals[i] = "" + i;

    // create a chartdata object that contains only the x-axis labels (no entries or datasets)
    LineData data = new LineData(xVals);

    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {

}


private LineDataSet createSet() {

    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "DataSet 1");
    set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
   // set.setCircleSize(4.5f);
    set.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 99, 99));
   // set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 99, 99));
    set.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(190, 190, 190));

    return set;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the xVals when you add a new entry. This will solve your problem.

Put your ArrayList global
`ArrayList xVals = new ArrayList();`

And when you add a new entre, update the list (for example)
`xVals.add("val"+i);`